# How to read data from HTML file using re function in Python

Tags: html, python-2.7

I want to get product names from the website URL by using Python, here is some sample code:

```
productFindData['appdna'] = [];    
productFindData['appdna'].push({ name: "product-software", title: "Product Software"});
productFindData['citrix-content-delivery-analytics'] = [];    
productFindData['citrix-receiver'] = [];    
productFindData['citrix-receiver'].push({ name: "windows", title: "Receiver for Windows"});
productFindData['citrix-receiver'].push({ name: "legacy-receiver-for-windows", title: "Earlier Versions of Receiver for Windows"});
productFindData['citrix-receiver'].push({ name: "mac", title: "Receiver for Mac"});
```

From the above I want to get only `appdna`, `citrix-content-delivery-analytics`, `citrix-receiver`.

Comment: I should have asked this before writing an answer.. In the question title you state "read data from html file" but in the first line of your question you say "from the website url", are you parsing the link or the website? My answer is for the website, it would be different for an url

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you don't write your own regex expressions for something that is so widely used as xml/dom.

I highly recommend that you use [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to parse your html file

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    tree = ET.parse('page.html')
    root = tree.getroot()
    for child in root:
       print(child.tag, child.attrib)
```

And read up about [XPath](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) on that same page for accessing interesting elements.